# How to use "windows folder path" "c:\bla\bla\" in R script variable without manual editing

Tags: r, substitution

I wish to copy and paste the windows full folder path in an R variable such as

```
wd <- "C:\Users\mike\DATA\Statistics_R_\output_examples"
```

even IF later on I have to use either sub or gsub to change those backslash into forwardslash.

I can't as it keeps giving me the following error:

> Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting
>   ""C:\U"

I found that this gsub 'coding' will work:
gsub(pattern="\\\\", replacement="/",wd)

BUT first, you have to **manually** change the path to add another backslash?
Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using these sub/gsub functions?

So this would work:

```
wd <- "C:\\Users\\mike\\DATA\\Statistics_R_\\output_examples"
gsub(pattern="\\\\", replacement="/",wd)
```

BUT this would not :

```
wd <- "C:\Users\mike\\DATA\Statistics_R_\output_examples"
gsub(pattern="\\", replacement="/",wd)
```

Maybe there is not a way to prevent R from interpreting a backslash, even if that backslash is inside a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `C:\Users\mike\DATA\Statistics_R_\output_examples` is on the clipboard then either of these will read it into `wd`:

```
wd <- readLines("clipboard")

wd <- readClipboard()
```

giving:

```
> wd
[1] "C:\\Users\\mike\\DATA\\Statistics_R_\\output_examples"
```

Whether you even need to change the backslashes depends on what you want to do with it.  You may not need to.  If you do then this would do it:

```
chartr("\\", "/", wd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you know if there is a way to prevent R from interpreting a backslash, even if that backslash is inside a string? For example, can you write in any sort of way, in any sort of variable, surrounded by any sort of separator the very basic simple string "c:\windows" ?

Comment: Enter this into R on one line `wd <- readLines(stdin(), 1)` and then on the next line enter this: `c:\windows`

Comment: BINGO! you nailed it. Many Thanks to you!!! I wish to ask for an additional question. You used the function chartr but I have mostly seen the function gsub used for string-search-and-replace. How different is that chartr from gsub?

Comment: You can use `gsub(..., fixed = TRUE)` too here.  Only used `chartr` because its shorter in this particular case, i.e. don't need `fixed=TRUE`.